# Как открывать в Ubuntu файлы *.php по FTP не через браузер?

Tags: ubuntu, файловая-система, ftp

Есть файл 1.php, расположен локально, если просто двойным кликом его открыть - открывается в vscode.

Если тот же файл кинуть на FTP, который примонтирован и доступен по адресу file:///run/user/1000/gvfs/ftp:host=****,user=*/1.php, то откроется chrome и в нём уже этот файл.

Если нажать по файлу на ftp правой кнопкой в Nautilus, там выбрать "открыть в другом приложении", а там "выбрать" при выделенном vscode - откроется через vscode нормально.

Нашёл ту же проблему, но без решения: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/483

Comment: А проблема в чем у вас? В вопросе нет описания на чем ломается и какие ошибки вы логируете.

Comment: если коротко - исользуйте ftp клиент. Гляньте filezilla

Comment: 21 век на дворе. FTP ?

Comment: Мне не нужен дополнительный клиент, Nautilus прекрасно справляется со своими обязанностями, единственный проблемный момент в вопросе

Comment: @Hellseher Никаких ошибок, всё как в вопросе и по ссылке в вопросе. Просто открывается не через назначенное приложение файл, а через браузер при двойном клике.